# handle multiple instances prisma warning in nestjs testing

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, prisma

I'm writing tests for a Nestjs API. when I run it, it gives this error:

```
warn(prisma-client) There are already 10 instances of Prisma Client actively running.
```

this is in my test where I instantiate Prisma:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService, PrismaService, RedisService],
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({
        envFilePath: `${process.cwd()}/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
        load: [configuration],
        cache: true,
      }),
    ],
  }).compile();

  controller = module.get<UserController>(UserController);
  service = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
  redis = module.get<RedisService>(RedisService);
  prisma = module.get<PrismaService>(PrismaService);
  await redis.onModuleInit();
  await prisma.customer.deleteMany({});
});

afterEach(async () => {
  await redis.onModuleDestroy();
  await prisma.onModuleDestroy();
});
```

and my prisma service:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleDestroy, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient
  implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy
{
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    try {
      await this.$connect();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.$disconnect();
  }
}
```

I inject and use prisma service into user service and I've written 11 tests by now. I need to clear customer table before each run and if I don't clear it, I don't get this error.can you help me with handling this error or offering a solution instead of clearing table?

Comment: This happens because each test is initializing its own Prisma module, each with its own connection pool to the database. Is it necessary to initialize the modules in a `beforeEach`? Perhaps you could use `beforeAll` for initialization, and only use `beforeEach` for deleting the customer table. 

I think this might solve the issue.

Comment: Hey, got a solution here?